# html file save restore from vba

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I want to re-use a snapshot of a web response for testing an app that needs to do some web-scraping. What I tried to do is just save the response (from Chrome) and reload the the string from the file:

```
doc.body.innerHtml = StringFromFile
```

This doesn't work though, although it *looks* like good html. By not work, I mean data that is in tag "Table"(6) when going through the web is not found. Is there a better way to load the html doc?

The code below is an attempt to both save an existing doc to file and then reuse it. Its worthless but maybe it will help someone set me straight on this.

Cheers

```
Private Function GetEWhipersTestHtmlDoc() As HTMLDocument
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Set doc = New HTMLDocument

Dim sText As String
sText = GetStringFromFile(GetFileName("UnconfirmedRelease"))
doc.body.innerHTML = sText
Set GetEWhipersTestHtmlDoc = doc
End Function

Private Function GetFileName(testName As String) As String
GetFileName = ThisWorkbook.path & Application.PathSeparator & _
    "Earnings Whispers Test Scenarios" & Application.PathSeparator & testName & ".txt"
Debug.Assert Dir(GetFileName) <> ""
End Function

Private Function SaveHtmlStringToFile(testName As String, sInnerHtml As String) As String
Dim fso As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim sPath As String

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sPath = GetFileName(testName)

Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(sPath)
oFile.WriteLine sInnerHtml
oFile.Close
End Function
```

### ** UPDATE **

Saving doc.body.outerHtml seems to be an upgrade from what I had. The text can turned into the web page using 'code snippet'. I am getting an error when trying to put the saved text back into a new document though:

```
Err 600, Application-defined or object-defined error

Private Function GetEWhipersTestHtmlDoc() As HTMLDocument
    Dim doc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim sText As String

'   Error Handling
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    sText = GetStringFromFile(GetFileName("UnconfirmedRelease"))

    doc.body.outerHTML = sText <---- ** ERROR is Here
    Set GetEWhipersTestHtmlDoc = doc

    Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    Select Case DspErrMsg("blah")
         Case Is = vbAbort:  Stop: Resume    'Debug mode - Trace
         Case Is = vbRetry:  Resume          'Try again
         Case Is = vbIgnore:                 'End routine
     End Select


End Function
```

### final update

thanks to Tim and David I got something usable. The only hair of Tim's final solution is that HtmlDocument.Write is restricted as far as VBA is concerned. So to 'fool' the compiler, I needed to declare it as an Object:

```
Dim doc As Object   <--- don't let vba know we want to write to HTMLDoc
Set doc = New HTMLDocument
Dim sText As String

sText = GetStringFromFile(GetFileName("UnconfirmedRelease"))
doc.Open
doc.Write sText  <-- no intellisense, but compiles...and works!
doc.Close
```

Comment: Saving the HTML from the document body will not save any content which is in the document HEAD: this may include scripts, style, etc which are required by the body to render correctly.  Try `doc.outerHTML` instead.

Comment: @Tim Williams. Thanks for that Tim. Please see UPDATE. Can you spot why I am getting that error?

Comment: `outerHtml` is a [read-only property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)...

Comment: Maybe try `doc.Open(): doc.Write(sText): doc.Close()`

Comment: Yeah, that got it done, with the wrinkle I noted in my last edit. I can give you the answer if you put it in an answer format too. Thks!